# SpriteKit nodes y position acts differently on different devices

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

So I am working on a game involving making pizzas, I want to draw a pizza node at the bottom of the screen, however I am have trouble making it line up consistently on every device.

Here is my code creating the pizza node:

```
    override init() {
        super.init()
        
        let image = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "plain_pizza")
        
        image.setScale(0.5)
        
        self.image = image

        self.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: (-UIScreen.main.bounds.height))

        self.addChild(image)
    }
```

And below is an image showing how it is displayed on an iPhone 11 vs an iPod touch v7.

On the iPod touch somehow setting the y pos to -height puts it in the perfect spot but on the iPhone 11 its off the screen. On the iPhone 11 it will show in the right spot if I do this instead

`self.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: (-UIScreen.main.bounds.height + (image.size.height*1.5))`

So why is the y position different on both devices? I would've thought it should work like the iPhone 11 on both. How can I make it always just appear at the bottom of the screen?

[image]

Comment: "why is the y position different on both devices?"  That's because they have different screen sizes and aspect ratios, obviously.  "How can I make it always just appear at the bottom of the screen?"  Well, you don't even explain under what class you are writing code.  So it's hard to say.  If you are writing code under SKScene, why would you even use `UScreen` there?

Comment: @ElTomato I understand the screen size will be different but if im basing its placement off of the screen then shouldn't it always be at the bottom? I am just creating this node using the shown init method and then adding it to an SKScene. I am very new to SpriteKit which is why i may be doing it strangly.

Comment: Try using the center of the scene as a relative reference to position sprites.

Comment: @ElTomato could you provide an example of how to do that so the pizza is always at the bottom? My understanding was `-UIScreen.main.bound.height` would be the bottom of the screen, so `-UIScreen.main.bound.height + pizzaNode.height` would make the bottom of the pizza be the bototm of the screen

Comment: @ElTomato What is wrong with my thinking? I dont care what the device screen size is, if its an iPad or the smallest iPhone i always want the pizza node bottom centre

Comment: Suppose that one device has the screen size of 600 pts x 1200 pts and that another has the screen size of 620 pts x 1500 pts.  If you place a sprite aligning to the bottom of the screen, your game will look totally different, depending on which device to use, don't you think?  That's not how you design games in SpriteKit.

Comment: Yes, it will look different depending on the device, I still want it at the bottom of the screen so the game will work in a way that is comfortable for how the user will be holding there phone - either way i dont understand why UIScreen.bounds.height is not always the edge of the screen, what is the UIScreen in that case?